# PL/SQL procedure with For Loop

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am rather new to PL/SQL and am trying to understand how to code for this issue.

I need to create 130 identical Tables, in 130 different Schemas using 130 different Tablespaces.  I can readily run the code, then do global Search/Replace for the next schema, run the code, and repeat.

What I want to do is write an anonymous block with

```
declare n number(3);
  Begin
   for n in 1..130 
   Loop

    (run my statements)

  End Loop;
End;
/
```

Currently the statements I am using is a straight SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE xyz_101.... Tablespace xyz_101
```

I am thinking I should create variables to hold all the Create Table, Alter Table, Create Index, Create Synonym syntax, then execute immediate this variables.  I am not completely certain how to do this as I will need pass "n" to each execution.

Is there a better way?  Should I write the "Create Table", Create Index", "Create Synonym" statements as cursors and then execute the cursors?

I am certain someone else has solved this problem and appreciate any guidance or insight.
Thank you!

Comment: Does `execute immediate 'create table xyz_:1 (...)' using n;` do the trick for you? If not, maybe `execute immediate 'create table xyz_' || to_char(n) || ' (...)'` does?

Comment: The second one. To my knowledge, you cannot use bind variables in DDL statements.

Comment: Sounds like a possibly outdated design.  A combination of Virtual Private Database features and Partitioning might be more maintainable.  Partitioning requires a license, though.

Comment: @HellmarBecker - worked perfectly.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE.

```
 for n in 1 .. 130 loop
       execute immediate 'create table t'||n||' ( dummy char(1) )';
 end loop;
```